# How to pass multiple checkbox values to wordpress query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, checkbox

I am working on a website that has multiple check boxes and I want to show results based on what user has selected.

There are about 16 check boxes for music, 8 check boxes for venues and 6 radio buttons for area. The user can check a maximum of 3 check boxes from Music category, a maximum of 3 from Venues and 1 from Area. How do I accomplish this wordpress query that would show posts only from categories that are selected.

For example, If a user has selected House, Techno and Dubstep in Music, Miami as Area, and they want to search for events, music festivals, and live venues, How can I get that using wordpress query?

```
    if(!empty($_POST)){
                global $names;
                $names  = $_POST['music'];
                $music = implode(",", $names);
                $echo $music;
      }
```

That will `echo` out all the selected checkboxes as house, dubstep, Miami, music festivals. Now I want to show posts that are in caegories of house, dubstep and are in music festivals category, and in miami area.

What I've used is

```
 $args = array (
      'category_name' => $music,
      'posts_per_page' => 12,
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC',
     );
$posts = query_posts($args);
```

But this will show all the posts from house, dubstep which is fine but it also shows all posts from music festivals that are not even in house and dubstep category.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters  category__and function

Comment: @user574632 Sorry but I have edited my question. Here I want something complex. Can you please help if you can. Thanks

Comment: lets say music is catid=1, house catid=2 and dubstep catid=5: replace 'category_name'=> $music, with 'category__and' => array(1, 2, 5),

Comment: Yeah but that changes everytime when the user searches. There are 16 category for music. If a user is a searching for techno, house and trance, then the above suggested solution would fail.

Comment: Thats just an example of how to use the category_and function - you would need to lookup the IDs each time, which is trivial http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID

Comment: wrote an answer to explain what i mean

Answer (score 0):

lookup the category ids and use category_and in your query:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
       $names  = $_POST['music'];
       $catIds=array();
       foreach($names as $name){
            $catIds[]=get_cat_ID($name);
       }

       $args = array (
           'category__and' => $catIDs,
           'posts_per_page' => 12,
           'orderby' => 'title',
           'order' => 'ASC',
       );
       $posts = query_posts($args);
}
```

Comment: @user3293145 what do you mean? What error are you getting

Comment: Like if I `print_r($catIds)` within `foreach` loop it shows category id of `31` for house which is wrong. `Array ( [0] => 0 ) techno
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 10 ) trance` This is what I mean.

Comment: @user3293145 please paste output of print_r($catIds); placed after the foreach loop